# Dúvida de como funciona o "import"

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

Estou aprendendo JS e ReactNative e para tal estou estudando sobre a criação de um backend em Node.js e um frontend em React Native e uma coisa me chamou a atenção.

Em meu backend quando o usuário é autenticado com sucesso é enviado como resposta um JSON contendo o nome, email e token JWT.

No meu frontend recebo tais informações e incluo o token no cabeçalho do AXIOS para ser usado em requisições futuras, exemplo:

Auth.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default class Auth extends Component {
   signin = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.post(`${server}/signin`, {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            })

            AsyncStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(res.data))
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `bearer ${res.data.token}`
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', res.data)
        } catch (e) {
            showError(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Bem, como podem observar eu incluo o token com o comando:

```
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `bearer ${res.data.token}`
```

Até aí tudo bem, o que me chamou a atenção é que em outros módulos eu consigo "aproveitar" esse token que foi adicionado no cabeçalho no módulo Auth.js. Por exemplo:

TaskList.js

```
import axios from 'axios'
export default class TaskList extends Component {
deleteTask = async taskId => {
        try {
            await axios.delete(`${server}/tasks/${taskId}`)
            this.loadTasks()
        } catch (e) {
            showError(e)
        }
    }
}
```

Sou leigo, mas parece que quando eu faço o import do axios no TaskList.js ele enxerga tudo o que eu fiz no axios do Auth.js, inclusive o token adicionado. É assim que funciona o import? Teriam algum texto sobre o assunto para eu devorar?

Até então eu imaginava o import como por exemplo uma constante, por exemplo, const axios, daí o que eu fizesse em um módulo não refletiria em outro.

Desde já agradeço a atenção de todos

Comment: `axios.defaults.headers` Você mandou colocar o token como um cabeçalho padrão...

Comment: @bfavaretto isso que ele fez seria um _Singleton_? O correto, talvez, seria passar esses valores no constructor ou na função.

Comment: @CmteCardeal, na verdade é [só um objeto](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js#L29). Como o objeto não é recriado a cada importação, a referência é sempre a mesma, o que permite esse tipo de "modificação", que persiste a todos os futuros importadores. No caso esse comportamento de _caching_ é exposto pelo [CommonJS](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching); no ESM, embora exista, é privado.

Comment: Assim como uma função declarada modulos es6 tem seu próprio context. O que acontece é que qnd você importa um arquivo com context existente o mesmo é conservado. O artigo que tenho que explica melhor isso está em inglês https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-module-system-for-state-management